# Buildar lib prophet em docker

Tags: docker

Estou tendo problemas para buildar um container com a lib prophet ja tentei de quase tudo porem sem sucesso. Já tentei instalar direto, e agor estou tentnado usar virtualenv e ainda sem sucesso.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7


LABEL MAINTAINER Leonardo Rodrigues
# Variáveis de ambiente
ARG PORT
ARG HOST 
ARG LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ARG DEBUG

# ENV DEBUG=False
ENV DEBUG=${DEBUG}
ENV PORT=${PORT}
ENV HOST=${HOST}


WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate


RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r requirements.txt --no-warn-script-location

RUN pip install pystan==2.18
RUN pip install pytz==2017.2
RUN pip install fbprophet

RUN useradd python

COPY --chown=python . /app

EXPOSE ${PORT}

USER python

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${PORT}
```

Mensagem de erro

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.163MB
Step 1/22 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> 84d66a048f90
Step 2/22 : LABEL MAINTAINER Leonardo Rodrigues
 ---> Running in 5caeb3889186
Removing intermediate container 5caeb3889186
 ---> 2d89013d2f52
Step 3/22 : ARG PORT
 ---> Running in 5554fd01ee7b
Removing intermediate container 5554fd01ee7b
 ---> d57cab74c8fa
Step 4/22 : ARG HOST
 ---> Running in d615ae639938
Removing intermediate container d615ae639938
 ---> d721e6ad4291
Step 5/22 : ARG LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 ---> Running in 4ac97ceedb80
Removing intermediate container 4ac97ceedb80
 ---> 5e93c9d498ab
Step 6/22 : ARG DEBUG
 ---> Running in 9b6b8e6f40f7
Removing intermediate container 9b6b8e6f40f7
 ---> 0f097182d7b1
Step 7/22 : ENV DEBUG=${DEBUG}
 ---> Running in b5a742e2050f
Removing intermediate container b5a742e2050f
 ---> b5535a55c0c3
Step 8/22 : ENV PORT=${PORT}
 ---> Running in 62d18fb577f9
Removing intermediate container 62d18fb577f9
 ---> c93c1cd45c1a
Step 9/22 : ENV HOST=${HOST}
 ---> Running in 713817af76af
Removing intermediate container 713817af76af
 ---> 2839fd846cf7
Step 10/22 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 699c12192c35
Removing intermediate container 699c12192c35
 ---> 01f5de706a90
Step 11/22 : COPY . /app
 ---> 97ca1bdfc884
Step 12/22 : RUN python3 -m venv venv
 ---> Running in be170350ea47
Removing intermediate container be170350ea47
 ---> c5fe833eacb9
Step 13/22 : RUN . venv/bin/activate
 ---> Running in 230519fb130e
Removing intermediate container 230519fb130e
 ---> acb0a7f4e853
Step 14/22 : RUN pip install pystan==2.18
 ---> Running in 4536bdec241d
Collecting pystan==2.18
  Downloading pystan-2.18.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (50.0 MB)
Collecting Cython!=0.25.1,>=0.22
  Downloading Cython-0.29.17-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.7
  Downloading numpy-1.18.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: Cython, numpy, pystan
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.17 numpy-1.18.3 pystan-2.18.0.0
Removing intermediate container 4536bdec241d
 ---> 7d0e07d85f06
Step 15/22 : RUN pip install pytz==2017.2
 ---> Running in 7be41c5af2da
Collecting pytz==2017.2
  Downloading pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz
Successfully installed pytz-2017.2
Removing intermediate container 7be41c5af2da
 ---> f2bb54e172b8
Step 16/22 : RUN pip install fbprophet
 ---> Running in 46aaa0e9d295
Collecting fbprophet
  Downloading fbprophet-0.6.tar.gz (54 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.17)
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.4
  Downloading cmdstanpy-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.18.3)
Collecting pandas>=0.23.4
  Downloading pandas-1.0.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.0 MB)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0
  Downloading matplotlib-3.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.4 MB)
Collecting LunarCalendar>=0.0.9
  Downloading LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting convertdate>=2.1.2
  Downloading convertdate-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting holidays>=0.9.5
  Downloading holidays-0.10.2.tar.gz (110 kB)
Collecting setuptools-git>=1.2
  Downloading setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.0
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23.4->fbprophet) (2017.2)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88 kB)
Collecting ephem>=3.7.5.3
  Downloading ephem-3.7.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.6
  Downloading PyMeeus-0.3.7.tar.gz (732 kB)
Collecting six
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting korean_lunar_calendar
  Downloading korean_lunar_calendar-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet, holidays, pymeeus
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-cf0bqsg6
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/fbprophet
  creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/setup.py", line 148, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
      build_models(target_dir)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
      from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
    File "/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/fbprophet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
    File "/tmp/pip-install-6siitsg7/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 15, in <module>
      import pandas as pd
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for holidays: filename=holidays-0.10.2-py3-none-any.whl size=111560 sha256=5975198a475531b314586b35cf490753ea4d14aa5f7d886e0126cee5c22c1e59  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/90/4e/82/f4130a57eb035c4344489ca14caff692590719b5f375540f53
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pymeeus: filename=PyMeeus-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl size=702876 sha256=9a52c21fb133ce9de1760fe697f766f0b1407cb4033d695b5897e290a5d76a70
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/80/32/5f/2a67880d4ce584b9cf99146f9945e46942dfb010a9382c6ff5
Successfully built holidays pymeeus
Failed to build fbprophet
```

O gerenciador de instalação pip informa o erro da falta da lib pandas, mas ela já está incluida nos requirements e tambem é instalada quando executo o comando

```
RUN pip install pystan==2.18
```

Answer (score 0):

Note que na mensagem de erro ta dizendo que falta instalar o pandas,
adiciona antes da linha:

```
RUN pip install fbprophet
```

a linha:

```
RUN pip install pandas
```

Comment: o pandas ja está instalado nos resquirements, o problema mesmo é a execução da instalação dessa lib

Answer (score 0):

Acabei encontrando a solução a partir do anaconda.

```
pip install -f https://pypi.anaconda.org/conda-forge/simple fbprophet
```

Esse comando é similar ao :

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Como me ajudou, espero que ajude alguem tambem